# javascript image slideshow works in all other browsers but not IE

Tags: javascript

I have an image slideshow which will work in any other browser I try but not in IE - it just does nothing but display the primary image.  Please could someone tell me I not going mad and it is a simple fix that I can't see.

Many thanks

Mickeyjay.

Code below:

```
<div id="image_slide"><img src="images/.......jpg" id="slideit" name="slideit" border="0">
<script type="text/javascript">
var dimages=new Array();
  var numImages=3;
  dimages[0]=new Image();
  dimages[0].src="images/.......jpg";
  dimages[1]=new Image();
  dimages[1].src="images/.......jpg";
  dimages[2]=new Image();
  dimages[2].src="images/.......jpg";
var curImage=-1;
function swapPicture()
{
  if (document.images)
  {
    var nextImage=curImage+1;
    if (nextImage>=numImages)
      nextImage=0;
    if (dimages[nextImage] && dimages[nextImage].complete)
    {
      var target=0;
      if (document.images.slideit)
        target=document.images.slideit;
      if (document.all && document.getElementById("slideit"))
        target=document.getElementById("slideit");
      if (target)
      {
        target.src=dimages[nextImage].src;
        curImage=nextImage;
      }
      setTimeout("swapPicture()", 1500);
    }
    else
    {
      setTimeout("swapPicture()", 150);
    }
  }
}
setTimeout("swapPicture()", 1500);
</script>
```

Comment: Which IE version? Did you check the error console? If there hasn't been an error, have you tried additional logging/debugging? Also `setTimeout("swapPicture()",delay)` is ___evil___ (see [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)). Use `setTimeout(swapPicture,delay)`.

Comment: Pretty ugly to poll for `.complete` rather than use `.onload` to get notified when the images are loaded.

Comment: @jfriend00: you're probably answering the question there. Not using ``onload`` means that there could be a race condition.

Comment: @mzedeler - I don't see a race condition.  If the code doesn't detect `.complete`, it just keeps polling until it is set.  It may be that some older versions of IE don't support `.complete`.

Comment: Note that the onload event for images *may* not fire if the image is loaded from the browser cache in IE.

Comment: @scunliffe - That issue is only a problem if you set `.src` before you set `.onload` (because onload fires before you've set a handler).  If you set `.onload` before `.src`, IE will always fire it when the image loads, even from cache.

Comment: Note: `.complete` has only been standardized recently in HTML5.  It's been around for awhile in various browser implementations, but it is worth checking whether all versions of IE support it.

Comment: @jfriend00 -you're right. I didn't take enough time to read the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simplified test, the idea is to load your pictures before start to swap, and will not need to test `.complete` that way.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="image_slide"><img src="intro.jpg" 
       id="slideit" name="slideit" border="0"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var curImage  = -1;
    var numImages = 2;
    var dimages   = new Array();

    function loadPictures()
    {
      dimages[0]     = new Image();
      dimages[0].src = "test1.jpg";
      dimages[1]     = new Image();
      dimages[1].src = "test2.jpg";

      setTimeout(swapPicture, 3000);
    }

    function swapPicture()
    {
      var nextImage = curImage + 1;
      if (nextImage >= numImages)
          nextImage = 0;

      document.images.slideit.src = dimages[nextImage].src;
      curImage = nextImage;
      setTimeout(swapPicture, 1500);
    }

    setTimeout(loadPictures, 1500);

  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```